# Google Maps SDK demo doesn't works with Swift 3.0

Tags: ios

I am using the google maps demo (http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial).   After updating my Xcode to latest Version the MapTasks.swift (https://github.com/appcoda/google-maps-api-demo) has many errors with swift 3. And some how I was fixed those errors but the map isn't works and the map is not loading as well.

So, Please help me to fix it , hence I've to update it in my Current working project.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the error

Comment: by default the apple map is taking delay for load we need to wait

Comment: No, I'm using Google Map. Unexpectedly found nil error where the mapView.delegate = self. and the mapView is an object of GMS Mapview

Comment: check one your mapview is optional ? or ! in your class

Comment: Im using mapview !

Comment: can you attach your project once

Comment: this is my number 8754846846 if you feel free call me, I think you were in india correct

Comment: I given my no when you are free call me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the Answer at https://github.com/BhavinBhadani/MapDemo thanks to Bhavin

Answer (score 0):

I guess the demo you use is a old demo. The most accurate way to try Google Maps demo is to get the demo directly from Google.

Here is a easy way to get it from Google using CocoaPods.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/code-samples